# ¿Cómo insertar la columna de Totales y % de los totales en una tabla previamente realizada? en PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, select, porcentaje

Necesito agregar la columna del total de las "Aprobadas", así obtener el % total de cada ID de campaña  y mostrarla a la derecha de la tabla de datos. Así como esta imagen..

[image: Resultado consulta deseada]

Me dificulta ya que este desglose tiene una condición de campañas exitosas, y necesito traer el total, sin estas condiciones en el SELECT, adjunto el código del desglose **sin la columna de totales %**

```
select r.campain_id as "Id campaña", 
       c.name as "Campaña", 
       r.question as "Pregunta", 
       COUNT(r.id) as "Total casos de éxito"
from responses r
inner join campains c on c.id_campain=r.campain_id
WHERE campain_id IN(2096,2097) 
  AND r.question IN('Éxito de la misión') AND r.response IN('Si')
GROUP BY c."name", r.question, r.campain_id
```

Answer (score 0):

La complejidad de tu problema, hasta donde entiendo, radica en que buscas calcular una columna proveniente de dos conteos con condiciones distintas. Te recomiendo que no busques resolverlo en una consulta. Podrías crear una función para realizar las siguientes acciones:

1. Crear una tabla temporal con los resultados esperados, por ejemplo:

```
create temp table _reporte 
        (id_campaña integer, campaña text, pregunta text, total_exito integer, 
           total_general integer default null, porcentaje integer default null)
```

2. LLenar la primera parte de la tabla con la consulta que ya tienes:

```
insert into _reporte (id_campaña,campaña, pregunta, total_exito) select r.campain_id as "Id campaña", 
       c.name as "Campaña", 
       r.question as "Pregunta", 
       COUNT(r.id) as "Total casos de éxito"
from responses r
inner join campains c on c.id_campain=r.campain_id
WHERE campain_id IN(2096,2097) 
  AND r.question IN('Éxito de la misión') AND r.response IN('Si')
GROUP BY c."name", r.question, r.campain_id
```

3. Actualizar la columna de *total general*. Este paso dependerá de tu cálculo para obtener esta información; puede ser un escalar o de la forma:

```
update _reporte 
       set total_general= a.total
      from (aquí iría la consulta que ya tienes pero con las condiciones que calculan el total general) a 
       where a.id_campaña=id_campaña`
```

4. Actualizar el porcentaje. Como ya tienes todos los valores en la tabla se calcula directo.
5. Retornas la temporal _reporte y procedes a eliminarla.